# button disable alert when condition met

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button that looks like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-default pull-right" 
    ng-disabled="subcategory.required2 == subcategory.completed2" 
    ng-click="open(subcategory)">Add Course <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
</button>
```

It gets disabled whenever the condition is met.

But now instead of disable i want to hide it and display an alert like:

```
<span class="alert alert-success">Requirement met</span>
```

How do i give the new condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a couple ng-if statements:

```
<button class="btn btn-default pull-right" 
ng-if="subcategory.required2 != subcategory.completed2" 
ng-click="open(subcategory)">Add Course <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
```

```
<span ng-if="subcategory.required2 == subcategory.completed2" class="alert alert-success">Requirement met</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can show or hide the button with ng-show:

```
<button class="btn btn-default pull-right" 
    ng-show="subcategory.required2 != subcategory.completed2" 
    ng-click="open(subcategory)">Add Course <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
</button>
```

Then add another ng-show with the inverse of the logic to your span:

```
<span class="alert alert-success" ng-show="subcategory.required2 == subcategory.completed2">Requirement met</span>
```